# jQuery Mobile footer navigation

Tags: jquery-mobile, jquery-mobile-listview

I am building a responsive design and would like to use jquery mobile to provide just a menu. I was looking towards nested listviews (I know they are deprecated in 1.3.0). What I am after is a nested set of links in the footer. When an item with children is clicked, the sub menu will slide in, otherwise just navigate to the link that was clicked if it has no children.

This fiddle shows what I am after http://jsfiddle.net/QfyZd/6/

I thought that I would get the desired effect by marking up the footer with:

```
data-role="footer" data-position="fixed"
```

My question is though, how do I ensure the listview only affects the footer rather than the entire page? Or am using the wrong components to achieve what i'm after?